# Split a Column Into 2 Using Regular Expression

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, lubridate

I have a dataframe that consists of time in the following format:

```
df<-data.frame(time=c("1655","1055","1123","1505"))
#   time
# 1 1655
# 2 1055
# 3 1123
# 4 925
```

I wanted to change it into the standard format, i.e. 16:55:00 with the colons, but using function `hms` in `lubridate` package would not work.

I was thinking of separating the `time` column into 2 such that I would have:

```
#   time1 time2
# 1 16    55
# 2 10    55
# 3 11    23
# 4  9    25
```

Then combine them back using `:` as a separator:

```
#   time
# 1 16:55
# 2 10:55
# 3 11:23
# 4 09:25
```

However, I am not certain on how to do it (esp. dealing with Regex). I tried:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
separate(time,c("time1","time2"),sep="[[:digit:]$]{2}") %>%
unite(time,time1,time,sep=":")
```

Of course, this would not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sprintf` to convert the 3 digit number to 4 digit by appending 0 at the beginning and then with `sub`, we match two characters at the beginning and capture as a group (`(.{2})`) and replace it with the backreference (`\\1`) followed by `:`.

```
df$time <- sub("^(.{2})", "\\1:", sprintf("%04d", as.integer(as.character(df$time))))
df$time
#[1] "16:55" "10:55" "11:23" "09:25"
```

Or another option is `str_pad` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
sub("(.{2})$", ":\\1", str_pad(df$time, 4, "left", pad = "0"))
#[1] "16:55" "10:55" "11:23" "09:25"
```

---

If we prefer `tidyverse`, the `separate/unite` can also work if we first `mutate` with the `sprintf`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
     mutate(time = sprintf("%04d", as.integer(as.character(time)))) %>% 
     separate(time, into = c("time1", "time2"), sep=2) %>%
     unite(time, time1, time2, sep=":")
#    time
#1 16:55
#2 10:55
#3 11:23
#4 09:25
```

Or with `str_pad/str_replace` from `stringr`

```
df %>%
   mutate(time = str_pad(time, 4, "left", pad = "0"),
          time = str_replace(time, "(.{2})", "\\1:"))
#   time
#1 16:55
#2 10:55
#3 11:23
#4 09:25
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(time=c("1655","1055","1123","925"))
```

NOTE: creating `data.frame` without using `stringsAsFactors` will by default use `stringsAsFactors=TRUE` so the column with be `factor`, and it is converted to `integer` with `as.integer(as.character` to be used as input for `sprintf`

Answer (score 1):

If you did want to use `lubridate` to have time stored as a `Period` you could use the something like the following

```
df<-data.frame(time=c("1655","1055","1123","1505","955"))
df$time2 <- hm(gsub("(.{2}$)",":\\1",df$time))
```

`gsub` inserts a ":" before the last two characters

`hm` from `lubridate` converts it to a `Period` object.